# Which selenium python package should I be using?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using `Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 2.4.0 (x86_64) on a Mac OS X 10.11.6`

Should I be using selenium-3.0.0b2 https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium

or should I be using selenium-2.53.6 https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium/2.53.6 which is the version which installs when I run `pip install -U selenium`

Both encounter problems when running and I don't want spend ages fixing a package which is indeed the wrong version for my machine

Comment: versions with `b` are usually beta versions. You most probably want to go with the most recent stable version, ie 2.53.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, using pip is quite a good practice.
Also, as far as I know, your problems more likely will be about communication with selenium-standalone and your selenium, so firstly you should check which bunch is stable at the moment.